# send log file from backend to UI using mmc rest API- logic for sending only the changes in file

Tags: java, file, logging, mule

I am trying to use rest APIs provided by mule management console to retrieve server log files. 
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Servers

My intention is to use this List File API

```
http://localhost:8080/mmc-console-3.4.0/api/servers/{serverId}/files/{relativePathToFile}[?metadata=true]
```

provided and display the logs in UI.

1) What should be the return type of the method I make as the above API call is returning a file? Would it be 'File' ?

2) Since the size of the mule_ee.log file could be large, I want to send the entire file for first call and from next call I just want to send the few lines appended at the last so that UI will do the appending and show it in console. Is this feasible ? Is there a better approach to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Servers) you will get the file itself. However there is no incremental mechanism.

For this matters you should probably use [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) or an advanced log distribution system.